# req.text[:200] in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

i have this following code,

```
  1 import requests
  2 
  3 r = requests.get('some link') 
  4 print (r.text[:200])
```

Does :200 stand for if status is ok then print?

Comment: It means "print the first 200 characters of the response body (or the entire body if it's shorter than that)".

Comment: I mean, just how could it possibly mean "if status is ok then print"?

Comment: I actually thought about that but I got confused when i tried googling it. Thanks for clarification, now i know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r.text[:200]` means print the first 200 characters of the response body

to check the status code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('some link') 
if r.status_code == 200:
    print ('good')
else:
    print ('bad')
```

one more way is by using `r.ok`

```
import requests
r = requests.get('some link') 
if r.ok:
    print ('good')
else:
    print ('bad')
```